# Estimating Cost of Querying a System and Developing Distributions

Tags: distributions, confidence-interval, sampling, optimization

Okay so,

Pretend you have a gum ball machine with many different colors. It cost $X to get a gum ball out of the machine. You want to take a sample to produce good distributions of the diameters of gum balls by color. However, the outside of the gum ball machine is complete dark, so you can't get a sense of the frequency of the colors of gum ball in the machine. In addition, you have the colors and diameters of all of the gum balls the last time it was filled, and you can assume that collection is similar to the one currently in the machine.

1. What sampling method would you use to pull gum balls out of the machine to develop reasonable distributions?
2. Can you/how can you estimate how much the total cost will be distributions of the diameters for each color with a set confidence interval/score (i'm actually pretty flexible on the target, just whatever makes sense in this context)?

Let me know if this problem is clear enough to make sense.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "sampling method"? According to your preliminary description, the *only* sampling method is to pay $X$ to "get a gum ball out."  How would you characterize "reasonable" distributions?

Comment: For the sampling method, I am trying to understand if it okay to continually draw samples until some condition is met like a maximum amount of money spent or some upper bound of standard deviation/SE/other property that measures predictive power. For the second part, I'm actually pretty flexible on the definition of reasonable. What I am looking for is some kind of stopping condition for making draws from the machine and for a way to forecast how might money you might spend for reasonably accurate estimates. This might be unacceptably vague, but lmk.

Comment: I am wondering if the way the gum balls would be pulled out is related to inverse sampling

https://www.statisticshowto.com/inverse-sampling/